# Склонение слова "туфли"

Tags: склонение

Как пишется слово "туфли" в единственном числе? А также в родительном падеже (множественном и единственном числе)?

Answer (score 1):

Им. ед.: *т**у**фля,* род. ед.: *т**у**фли,* род. мн.: *т**у**фель.* Подобные орфографические затруднения решаются в словарном порядке.

Comment: Так же ,как тапка, кроссовка. Только здесь не орфографическое затруднение, а грамматическое.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую прочесть во избежание бессмысленных споров, ибо тоже задалась вопросом, а не подводит ли меня моя интуиция, когда я говорю "вне правила" и т.п.
[http://bitclass.ru/rus/theory/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6.*%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0*%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85](http://bitclass.ru/rus/theory/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6._%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)